# Rails 3 - Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, builder

I would like to ask you about bundler… if I run command "bundle list", so I will get list of gems and is there "* rake (0.9.2)", but if I move my app to server, I am getting error **Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)** — but this gem is in bundler… what could be wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Could you please elaborate on how you solved this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should package the gems with the application.

http://gembundler.com/bundle_package.html

Comment: I tried to do... I ran the command **bundle package** and then **cap deploy:cold** for moving app to server, but still the same problem - **Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources**

Comment: Is the gem in the tmp/cache folder (on the server's release)?

Comment: Hi, I solved my problem thanks to update bundler on version >= 1.0.13

Answer (score 1):

`rm -rf Gemfile.lock` then re-run `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

+1 for tamaresalama's answer...

which version of Rails are you using?

make sure all your gem-dependencies are listed in the "Gemfile" .. then run "bundle install"

If you use RVM, you should also create a specific gemset for your application, to encapsulate your gems for that application better. e.g. 'rvm gemset create yourname'

After you created the new gemset, you can set it as the default using 'rvm gemset use yourname --default'  you then need to do a manual 'gem install rake" to make sure it's in the new gemset, before you do a 'bundle install'

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to my Gemfile solved the problem. For some reason I removed it previously.

Answer (score 0):

Showing following error for me when run command bundle install,
"*Could not find rails_best_practices-1.13.7 in any of the sources*"

Just **delete** the **Gemfile.lock** and working for me.